# Most efficient way co compare two DOMStrings if they represent the same DOM node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-node

I use ReactJs function *renderToStaticMarkup* to create HTML Markup. The markup is on another place in the App set as the **innerHTML** property to other DOM node. Since I would like to prevent *images* and *iframes* from re-rednering, I would like to make comparison, if the current **innerHTML** is the different from the one it should be set to.

```
if (!domNode.innerHTML !== newMarkup);
    domNode.innerHTML = newMarkup;
}
```

For some reason, Reacts *renderToStaticMarkup* creates HTML Markup for **images** as:

```
<img src="https://placebeard.it/200x150" alt="" class="content-media-image-linked"/>
```

but the DOM *innerHTML* has a value of

```
<img src="https://placebeard.it/200x150" alt="" class="content-media-image-linked">
```

So basically the difference IS in the trailing `/` (but this does not need to be the rule of thumb)

I wonder what would be the **most efficient/fast way** to determine, whether those two DOMStrings represent the same DOM Node.

### 1. String Comparison

It would be *probably* enough to replace/remove all occurrences of `/>`

### 2. Parsing/converting to DOMNodes

This is more safe method, but also much more expensive. I would have to use something like `document.createRange().createContextualFragment` (see [this post](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-html-stings-dom-nodes)) and than use the `isEqualNode` method.

Has aonyone some better sugeestion ?

Comment: I'd expect the `innerHTML` of an `img` element to be a blank string, and a quick test seems to support that. Do you mean **`outerHTML`**?

Comment: what about whitespace inside the nodes? Would different whitespace consider a different node? like `<span>lorem ipsum</span>` vs `<span>   lorem   ipsum 
  </span>`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "'I'd expect the innerHTML of an img element to be a blank string ..." The img Dom-node is not the one, on which  _ innerHTML_ is called. The _ innerHTML_ is called on its parent - the container.

Comment: @karlitos - That explains it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As I think you know, the `/` in `/>` at the end of a tag has no meaning whatsoever in HTML (it does in XHTML and JSX), so my temptation would be

1. Change the `/>` to `>` and compare; if they match, they're the same.
2. If they don't match, parse it and use `isEqualNode`

The first gives you the quick win in what I assume will be the majority case. The second works the slower but more robust way, allowing attributes to be in a different order without introducing a difference (unless it makes a difference), etc.

When replacing the `/>` with `>`, be sure of course to only do so in the right place, which may or may not be tricky depending on the strings you're dealing with (e.g., to they contain nested HTML, etc.). ("Tricky" as in "you can't just use a simple regular expression" if the HTML isn't of a single element like your `img` example.)

Comment: Do you have an example where /> could not be replaced? As far as I know ">" should be escaped in any attribute or text node. The only cases I could imagine it appearing verbatim, but not being a self closing end (besides malformed nodes) are a comment or script-tag? - where it could be replaced for comparisons sake...

Comment: @Falco - `>` is perfectly valid in both text and attribute values. It *can* be written with an entity, but it doesn't have to be and it very often isn't (particularly in old-fashioned `onxyz` attribute event handlers doing comparisons). `/>` an unlikely combination, though, I would have said...

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix to my issue was performing *sanitization* of the HTML Markup produced by the _ renderToStaticMarkup_ call. In my case the markup is generated only occasionally, but the Dom-Node equality check very often, so I went with just plain string quality-check.

I tried multiple libraries to achieve that:

[**sanitize-html**](https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html#readme) lokked promissing, but was not removing the trailing `/`

[**html-minifier**](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) worked, but I had issues using it with **es6 imports**

I ended up using [**dompurify**](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)